# How can I get last update time from ssh

Tags: updates, ssh

I'm having problems getting last update time(like I see sometimes in Update Manager).

Do you think it's possible to get from SSH a file/command that will show last update check for the current system ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the /var/log/apt/history.log.
This file contains information of when, what was updated and how long it took. The field 'Commandline' can also tell whether the update was run automatically or by hand.

To find out the time of last update check have a look at these files:

- /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-stamp #the time of a daily update check
- /var/lib/apt/periodic/update-success-stamp #the time of last update-check. For example if you have run `apt-get update` manually some time later

Comment: @lonut, please provide some feedback - have you tryied this? what did you get? was that helpful?

Comment: hello, sorry for the late answer... what i want is to see same result as it is in the right side (last update 6 hour ago) http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=0de5fb8 ...

Comment: @Ionut, updated my answer. I have also found a similar discussion [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/20747/find-last-time-update-was-performed-with-apt-get), but not all answers are correct.